# How to set exact instruction `gdb` puts a breakpoint on?

Tags: gdb

Given code like that (assume line number is `x`):

`if (condition) return false;`

...if `b x` is used to set breakpoint at that line, it would break on condition evaluation. How do I instruct `gdb` to put breakpoint **on the same line but different instruction**? In my case target is `return false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I

You can set a breakpoint on any instruction you want with `b *0x1234` syntax. Example:

```
(gdb) disas $pc
Dump of assembler code for function main:
=> 0x0000555555555040 <+0>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000555555555042 <+2>:     cmp    $0x1,%edi
   0x0000555555555045 <+5>:     setg   %al
   0x0000555555555048 <+8>:     retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *0x0000555555555045
Breakpoint 2 at 0x555555555045
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000555555555045 in main ()
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x555555555045 <main+5>:     setg   %al
```